# Testing a reference voltage of a ECU

Tags: microcontroller, testing, voltage-reference

I have test a condition when reference voltage(5V) from an ECU is not there. The ECU uses the supply voltage and internally generates the reference voltage using voltage regulator. The reference voltage is use for sensor/switches. I have to test for condition when the reference voltage is not available. My thinking was connecting a resistor to output of the reference pin and lower the resistance until the regulator cant sustain the current ouput.  Is there any other way of going about this?

Comment: If the reference voltage is not there just measure its lack of presence with a voltmeter.

Comment: I am trying to create condition of absent of reference voltage.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way of going about this?

Yes - to simulate the "condition of absent of reference voltage", simply cut the PCB track (or equivalent change) to disconnect the output of the voltage regulator supplying the reference voltage, from the rest of the circuit.

**But**

Total loss of the reference voltage (as you described) is only one of *many* possible failure modes of the reference voltage. If you only test for complete loss of the reference voltage, then you are only simulating a limited percentage of possible faults that could occur with the reference voltage.

I am not a specialist test engineer, but I can easily think of several more possible *failure modes* of the reference voltage, which could (and, imho, should) be tested for sane behaviour, with something as important as an ECU.

Comment: Sam, thank you for the answer. I cannot open the ECU so only modification will have to be external.  Also can you tell me other failure mode of reference voltage?

Comment: @user46261 - "I cannot open the ECU so only modification will have to be external" - In that case, you may not be able to simulate what you requested. You need to supply information about what signals / connections which you *can* access, for readers to then consider how they can be manipulated. "can you tell me other failure mode of reference voltage" - Yes, I can, but I don't want to waste time, if nothing will change from my reply. Who is setting the test requirements? Are you able to modify those requirements? Are you writing a test plan, or following a test plan written by someone else?